# If I compare conditions within two preexisting groups is that a quasi-experimental design?

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, experiment-design, group-differences

I have two groups of participants, one group of psychosis patients and one group of controls. All of the participants complete a computer task that has three different conditions.

So, I want to make both within- and between-groups comparisons. Since the differentiating factor between the groups is illness condition (something that can't be manipulated), I figured I run a mixed design ANOVA (split-plot ANOVA). Thus, labeling psychosis and healthy as two independent variables. Is this analysis right?

If it is right, what do I call this type of design? Would it be appropriate to call it "Quasi-experimental independent groups repeated measures design"?

Comment: what do you mean a computer task that has three different conditions? Would a simple ANOVA be the appropriate analysis?